# Zip generated files in Colab

Tags: python, zip, google-colaboratory, drive

How could I zip some files that I generated in google colab?

I have a bunch of PDF files that I generated with my code. I want them to be ziped in one file in order to download that zip file containing everything.
There could be hundred of files generated and that is why I do not want to download them one at a time.

Thanks

PD: I don't want to upload those files to my Drive so the solution `!zip -r '/content/folder/"NewFileName.zip"' '/content/folder/"OrginalFileName"'`
is not valid for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
!touch a.pdf
!touch b.pdf
!touch c.pdf
!zip all.zip *.pdf
```

[image]

Obviously change the zip command to point to your files in Colab.

Comment: That was perfect! Cheers